# Can I copy a logo for personal use?

Tags: logo, copyright

I wanted to make a logo for 3 friends of mine, just for fun. They asked me if I could make a logo for them, because they simply want a team logo for a video game they all play competitively. Nothing fancy. It's not for sale nor is it to be printed out.

I found this logo of a football team, and I really liked the design. Is it OK for me to create my logo using another logo's elements and tweaking a few things. I'm new to graphic design and I wanted to make sure that it was ok for me to create a logo by copying a few things just for the purpose of making it for my friends.

Comment: As long as your friends dont share it forward and it stays between your circle then theres nothing illegal. But try showing it at school or other official place such as screen casting on the net and your in trouble. I am not a lawyer, and certainly not your lawyer though. So this is not legal advice, and for that this is the wrong forum.

Comment: I'd suspect it's fair use if it's just for you and not to promote anything. But http://law.stackexchange.com may be a better place to ask.

Comment: For personal use, nothing will ever come from it. But keep in mind that this is a perfect excuse to do your own thing. A designer should love making logos. :)

Answer (score 1):

### **A better place to ask would be [law.stackexchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/).**

I am not a lawyer so do not take this as legal advice, but I will share my thoughts anyway. The important part of your question is this:

> they simply want a team logo for a video game they all **play competitively**

The only way I can understand this is that the logo will be used online, effectively in public, to represent the team (correct me if I'm wrong). I'm not sure exactly *how* competitively you mean by [competitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESports), and I'm not sure how that would affect the legal implications anyway - but, if this will be shown in public to represent (and arguably promote) a competitive team, I would say there's a good chance it isn't covered by fair use.

### My advice - Design the logo yourself.

Take inspiration from the logo you found. You can recreate the general layout or shape or typography or whatever it is that you like about it, but don't just take the logo and use it as is.

Comment: Yes. A thousand times yes. Even if in a totally non-commercial context, and even if a lawyer could somehow guarantee to you that you are not breaking the law, we all learn in Kindergarten to make our own work. Make the logo yourself and it will be a thousand times more valuable to you than the time and effort it took.